# Django: 'RegisterEmployeeView' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python, django

Am developing using django and i get AttributeError at /employee/register upon executing my runserver.

this is the code in my views.py

```
class RegisterEmployerView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = EmployerRegistrationForm
    template_name = 'accounts/employer/register.html'
    success_url = '/'

    extra_context = {
        'title': 'Register'
    }

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        return super().dispatch(self.request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        form = self.form_class(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return redirect('accounts:login')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/employer/register.html', {'form': form})
```

[TRACEBACK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt4aU.png)

Comment: can you show the foll stack trace of the error

Comment: I added the traceback screenshot

Comment: I am not sure but could it be that you need to add the FormMixin to make the get_success_url work properly?